# Image storing on S3 publicly returns false

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, laravel-9

The following code returns a path and an image gets uploaded to S3 (as a working code reference):

```
dd(Storage::disk('s3')->put('images/', $file));
```

Once I add either `'visibility' => 'public'` to the s3 driver in `config/filesystems.php` or `'public'` as 3rd argument (`$options`) of put, it returns false.

In the s3 bucket configuration I disabled blocking of public access.

The following code returns false as well:

```
$path = Storage::disk('s3')->put('images/', $file);
dd(Storage::disk('s3')->setVisibility($path, 'public'));
```

Following the Laravel documentation, they recommend the usage of

```
Storage::putFile('photos', new File('/path/to/photo'), 'public');
```

but the `putFile` function is not available when I use

```
Storage::disk('s3')->putFile('photos', new File('/path/to/photo'), 'public');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with putFileAs, Ex:

```
$path: s3 Path
$image: Uploaded Image
$fileName: Filename

Storage::disk('s3')->putFileAs($path, $image, $fileName, 'public');
```

Comment: `Undefined method 'putFileAs'`. It is the same as `putFile`.

Comment: Are you already to run this code?